# How to use in_array with belongsToMany relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm using `belongsToMany` with the model `Riskarea` because I have a pivot table called `riskarea_fields` which join the `Riskfield` model among `Riskarea`:

```
class Riskarea extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'riskareas';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'icon',
    ];

    public function riskfields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Riskfield::class,
            'riskarea_fields',
            'area_id',
            'field_id'
        );
    }
}
```

In my `edit.blade.php` I have this code:

```
@foreach ($riskfields as $rf)
    <option value="{{ $rf->id }}" @if (old('active', in_array($riskarea->riskfields, $rf->id))) selected="selected" @endif>
        {{ $rf->name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate over the `riskfields` property and select all riskfields options that are within `riskarea->riskfields`.

Unfortunately I got:

> in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, int given

This is my edit method:

```
public function edit(Riskarea $riskarea)
{
    return view('riskareas.edit', [
        'riskarea' => $riskarea,
        'riskfields' => Riskfield::all()
    ]);
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to check if each id is present in the associated riskfields, pluck their IDs before hand.

```
public function edit(Riskarea $riskarea)
{
    return view('riskareas.edit', [
        'riskarea' => $riskarea,
        'selectedRiskfieldIds' => $riskarea->riskfields()->pluck('id')->toArray(),
        'riskfields' => Riskfield::all(),
    ]);
}
```

Then you can do

```
@foreach ($riskfields as $rf)
    <option value="{{ $rf->id }}" @if (old('active', in_array($rf->id, $selectedRiskfieldIds))) selected="selected" @endif>
        {{ $rf->name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip! Is there a way to use only `$riskarea->riskfields`, so avoiding creating a new variable?

Comment: with this solution you avoid making a collection of the riskfields of the risk area and only get their Ids.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small mistake. You are using the in_array() function incorrectly. The syntax is: `in_array(mixed $needle, array $haystack)` . You've got it backwards. To use the in_array function you also need an array. Therefore, you convert the collection into an array. You do this with the Laravel function `toArray()`.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray.
Change it in your blade file from:

`in_array($riskarea->riskfields, $rf->id)`

**to**

`in_array($rf->id, $riskarea->riskfields->toArray()))`.

`in_array(mixed $needle, array $haystack, bool $strict = false): bool`
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Comment: Yep, you're right thanks! But now I get this: `n_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`

Comment: @sfarzoso then change it to: `in_array($rf->id, $riskarea->riskfields->toArray()))?`

Comment: Yes, this fix the error but no value is selected, I guess because the array is associative and I have to use `array_column`?

Comment: @sfarzoso Since you are directly at your code, you must know best. But it's worth a try ;-) you can dump an share the dump in your question.

Comment: @sfarzoso another solution would be to get the ids in array before hand. check my answer.